# Does non-visible light also experience refraction?

Tags: optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, refraction

Does non visible light such as x-rays or ultraviolet experience refraction and is their refraction index affected by their wavelengths (in their own spectrum)? Do they experience dispersion like visible light?

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Did you attempt any research on your own before asking the question here?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. UV is beyond the blue and violet after a prism. But glass is not transparent very far into the the UV, the rest gets absorbed. For vacuum-UV (beyond about 10 eV photon energy) there are no materials to make prisms of.

At much higher photon energies, in the x-ray region, materials become more transparent again. But the refractive index is very close to 1. And actually it is a tiny bit *smaller* than 1 (away from absorption edges). This is used to make mirrors for grazing incidence that have total reflection.

Comment: Yeah, but you can take a thin gas or a thin slice of material, and it will still transmit UV. That doesn't much change the answer, though - the UV will experience dispersion, but the small optical depth will make it very small.

Comment: Similarly, x-ray prisms are hard to make but not impossible.

Comment: Yes. And one can makes x-ray lenses too. The hard thing is to make x-rays sources where they are useful: insertion devices at synchrotrons.